# Vue.js + TS + Capacitor FCMPlugin has no construct signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, capacitor

I am trying to integrate firebase with Capacitor + Vue3 + TS. I installed @capacitor-community/fcm and I am importing it on App.vue as stated in this [tutorial](https://dev.to/marcoimproda90/how-to-configure-firebase-push-notifications-with-ionic-vue-js-38n7) I am following . I imported FCM from the capacitor library and when I try to initialize fcm variable with new FCM() object value it throws me the following error.

> "This expression is not constructable.   Type 'FCMPlugin' has no
> construct signatures.ts(2351)"

```
<script lang="ts">

import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      fcm: new FCM(),
    };
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: The official documentation shows no constructior, maybe they updated since 05/2021. More here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm

Comment: @savageGoat thank you!! It helped! I was implementing it the wrong way. Now it works. Thank you